# NSArray containsObject: faster alternative?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I did some runs on my iOS app with Instruments and I saw that 90% of the load on the main thread on launch (about 1000ms total) is caused by containsObject: calls. That's on the main thread and I don't think it's cool.

Is there a faster alternative to this method? An algorithm or another method?

Any suggestions?

**MORE INFO:**

1. I looked into my code again I realized that in fact I don't need to know the order of the objects, only if an object is part of that set. Which means NSSet will do just fine (and I guess is faster).
2. Number of objects - there may very well be 1000+ objects in that set.

Comment: Isn't `NSSet` better optimised for this sort of thing? You may want to develop your own `hash` method (and `equals:` as they are a couple).

Comment: As a side note, how big is the array? I didn't realise but the docs for `containsObject` says it'll check all members of the array, which sounds frankly a bit baffling so I'm hoping the docs are wrong.

Comment: @NikolayDyankov Bear in mind that a set also requires distinct, (non duplicated) values. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, they will all be unique for sure. The objects are fetched from Core Data, and new ones only get inserted if no such object exists in that fetched array/set. This checking thing will be done many many times on launch, so checking if the object exists in core data by making a request is not an option.

Comment: Using NSSet, you probably won't even have to check if an object is in the set, adding it again... won't add it again

Comment: So basically I say addObject:, and if the count of the NSSet hasn't changed, then the object exists in the set, correct?

Comment: I'll say "Yes", but I would check it yourself =]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you **NEED** to use an array, skip a bit further down

---

### Alternate Options

Your other options might include:

- Using an `NSDictionary` which uses key->value pairs which (I expect will) have O(1) read complexity at the cost of extra storage space for the keys
- If you aren't using duplicates and order isn't important, using an `NSSet` will offer better read complexity (I don't know what the complexity will be, the docs probably will)

---

### Using an Array

If you keep the array sorted, searching can be done in `O(log n)` time instead of `O(n)` as you can take advantage of a binary search.

***Caveat Lector**: This was written from memory*

```
-(void) /*adding*/
{
    int proposedIndex = 0;
    proposedIndex = [array indexOfObject:node
                                inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, array.count)
                                      options:NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex
                              usingComparator:
                      ^ NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
                      {
                          if (obj1.valueToCompare < obj2.valueToCompare) return NSOrderedAscending;
                          if (obj1.valueToCompare > obj2.valueToCompare) return NSOrderedDescending;
                          else return NSOrderedSame;
                      }];

    [array insertObject:node atIndex:proposedIndex];
}


-(id) /* Getting */
{
    int location = [array indexOfObject:node
                                    inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, array.count)
                                          options:NSBinarySearchingFirstEqual
                                  usingComparator:
                          ^ NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
                          {
                              if (obj1.valueToCompare < obj2.valueToCompare) return NSOrderedAscending;
                              if (obj1.valueToCompare > obj2.valueToCompare) return NSOrderedDescending;
                              else return NSOrderedSame;
                          }];
    if (location == NSNotFound) return nil;
    return [array objectAtIndex:location];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `NSSet containsObject` more faster than `NSArray`

Comment: Initially I thought that NSSet has better performance than NSArray when searching for an object, however even NSSet iterated through all objects and check if it exists or not which is same as NSArray.
Excerpt from NSSet documentation -
Each element of the set is checked for equality with anObject until a match is found or the end of the set is reached. Objects are considered equal if isEqual: returns YES.